# How can I tell what Apache (php) processes are holding open mem cache connections

Tags: php, apache, memcached

At times I have very high memcache current connections - how can I tell what is holding them open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a command like `lsof` will help you:

```
sudo lsof | grep -i 'tcp.*11211'
```

will list all of the pids that have opened tcp connections to memcached.